# Converting xml file data in js object

Tags: reactjs, xml, filereader, libxml-js

I need some help. I have an app that takes *.xml file through input type file, and converts it into js object.
To do that i am using FileReader and xml-js library from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

Now I have two problems that I can't handle.

1. xml file contains cyrillic symbols, in console they display as ������� ��� ���
   [image]

2. The second problem is that, in some reasons, I can't set converted object in state.

Here is my code:
Handler and input for file:

```
handleFile = (event) => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        let json = xmljs.xml2js(reader.result, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
        this.setState({
            file: json
        }, console.log ('file', json))
    }
};

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So what shouls I do to display cyrillic symbols and how to set the object in state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
Now my code looks so:

```
handleFile = (event) => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, 'windows-1251');
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        let json = xmljs.xml2js(reader.result, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
        this.setState({
            file: json
        }, () => {console.log('state', this.state)})
    }
};

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I added 'windows-1251' to define the encoding type, it helps with cyrillic symbols.
Also i changed callback function after setState to () => {console.log('state', this.state)} after that I can see a current state, with contetnt fron xml file.